# C++ линия, нарисованная через HDC LineTo(), мерцает

Tags: c++, winapi

При запуске, программа должна рисовать короткую линию по середине экрана (Поверх всех программ).
Линия рисуется, все хорошо, но очень сильно мерцает. Как решить проблему?

Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>
#include <stdio.h>


using namespace std;

int main() {
    int y = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int xs = 0;
    int ys = 0;

    RECT desktop;
    const HWND hDesktop = GetDesktopWindow();
    GetWindowRect(hDesktop, &desktop);

    x = desktop.right / 2;
    y = desktop.bottom / 2 - 2;

    xs = desktop.right / 2 - 2;
    ys = desktop.bottom / 2;

    HPEN pen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 8, RGB(255, 0, 0));

    HDC dot = ::GetDC(0);

    for (;;) {
        SelectObject(dot, pen);
        MoveToEx(dot, x, y, NULL);
        LineTo(dot, x, y + 4);
        Sleep(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вам стоит создать прозрачное [layered окно](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/window-features#layered-windows), расположить его поверх других окон и рисовать на нем. Более современная альтернативы - использование direct composition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Цикл не нужен, Вы постоянно перерисовываете линию, поэтому она и мерцает. Достаточно нарисовать линию и остановить выполнение программы. Также важно освобождать ресурсы.

```
HPEN op = (HPEN)SelectObject(dot, pen);
//for (;;) 
{
    MoveToEx(dot, x, y, NULL);
    LineTo(dot, x, y + 40); // 
    //Sleep(10);
}
SelectObject(dot, op);
DeleteObject (pen);
ReleaseDC (0, dot);
getchar();
```

Ну и конечно, как только произойдет перерисовка, то линия затрется.  Именно поэтому лучше создать прозрачное окно и перерисовывать линию по событию WM_PAINT окна. В этом случае линия будет перерисовываться, когда приложение будет становится активным.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!